# How to control Computer RGB LEDs in Linux

Tags: linux, led, motherboard

Since I switched to a new AMD Ryzen system my computer lit up.
All new hardware components seem nowadays to have such fancy(?) RGB-LEDs built-in (even in memory modules, even the stock CPU-cooler from AMD).

Is there a way to switch all LEDs in my system off.

The BIOS settings don't offer any control over the LEDs.

Only the mainboard's manufacturers utility software (all for Windows) seems to be capable of controlling that lightning in my computer case.

Is there a way to control such LEDs through Linux Operating System?

Comment: try openrgb [https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/releases]

Comment: @SudhirDhumal OpenRGB is a great project - Do you mind to give it as answer on the newly create question on superuser.com?
https://superuser.com/questions/1624884/how-to-control-computer-rgb-leds-in-linux

Comment: Check answer on superuser

Comment: There is only  1 solution. Install RGB fusion on windows and you can turn of the LED for all system. Linux or windows.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but just saw this so...for what it is worth...
While most PC mainboard and peripheral manufacturers have created their own proprietary schemes for RGB control via Windows software, some EFI settings allow the mainboard control of them to be turned off. Look into your EFI menus to see if you have that option. I have only Asus mainboards, but they have an option for "stealth" which turns them all off. Otherwise you get that saccharine oscillating rainbow color effect. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I run an Asus Tuf B450 with AMD and yes it lights up lie christmas
O.O >blink<

When it starts up press F2 to go into BIOS. There is a top note for Asus Aura. On mine pressing F4 or clicking the slider to off kills all the LED on the board...ALL

Mrs J